# Highcharts date parsing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, highcharts

I'm using highcharts for graphical showcase of statistics.
As I understand it,highcharts uses UTC time to parse datetime.In my case,datetime and value both coming from jagged array.When I use only value its fine,when the datetime value enters the case,highcharts does not parse datetime.

I prepared an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/myra/SPSyb/)

Datetime in here coming from a string so i must format (**dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss**)
For this I use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to parse my datetime value.But still no results.

Why highcharts does not render dates properly ?
What is the problem here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Original code excerpt**

```
var date = moment(graphData.items[i].Date, "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
xdata.push([date._d, graphData.items[i].Value]);
```

There's a format issue. Instead of `"dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss"` you should rather use `"DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss"`, as stated in the **[documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string+format)**.

I would also replace the call to the private member `_d` with a `.native()` invokation.

Last, but not least, HighCharts excepts to be fed with the number of milliseconds since Epoch. This can be achieved with a call to  `getTime()`.

**Fixed code**

```
var date = moment(graphData.items[i].Date, "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss").native();
xdata.push([date.getTime(), graphData.items[i].Value]);
```

A working patched version of your code is available **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/SPSyb/5/)**.